# How to display category page in magento

Tags: magento, categories

I'm using magento 1.5.0.1. In my home page i want to display categories, i have created 3 categories and gave is active option to yes in admin. I want to display these categories with link in my homepage. In the homepage i have these code

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_new" template="catalog/product/new.phtml" after="product_list"><action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>bundle</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block><template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template></action></block>
</reference>
```

How to change this to view categories. I'm new to magento. Please help me out of this......

I have given Include in Navigation Menu to yes while adding the categories.

Answer (score 7):

You can use build in widget "Catalog Category Link".

1. Open your magento backend
2. Navigate to CMS->Page
3. Select "Home Page"
4. Choose tab "Content"
5. Click on button "Insert Widget..."
6. Choose widget "Catalog Category Link" from list of available widgets.
7. Fill widget required information and click on "Insert Widget" button
8. Repeat step 5-7 for each category that your need to display on home page